# ClickOnce performance on a VB.NET application accessing SQL Server DB

Tags: vb.net, performance, clickonce

I have upgraded a 60 KLOC Windows VB.NET application to VS 2012 and Windows 8.
Everything looked fine, except when I deployed it yesterday to ClickOnce.

The ClickOnce application is incredibly slow to load every form the first time that form is launched, IF the form uses binding. If a form is not using binding (but selecting data from a DB query) they load normally.

The most funny part is that while debugging in VS2012 they load in less then 1 second. When launched from the ClickOnce version they spend more than 60 seconds to load.

If I close one of these forms in the ClickOnce application and re-open it, they load normally in less then 1 second.

It seems that Binding in VS2012 is very bad the first time a form is loaded, but I prefer to think I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas about this issue?

EDIT 2013/01/18:

After one day cutting unnecessary code, I have arrived to a solution that reproduces the slowness and that has no unnecessary code, so that it will be easier (I hope) to find what is not working proprly in it.

ClickOnce application is here:

http://www.octet.it/Reproduce/

Source files are here:

http://www.octet.it/Reproduce/Reproduce.zip

I can state that slowness is NOT depending on:

1. SQL Server (I have cut all the code that was accessing SQL server DB).
2. Binding (there is no binding at all, now).
3. Development environment: if you run the application from VS2012 it works as expected.

Instruction for reproducing slowness:

- Install the ClickOnce application on a Windows 8 machine (mine is
  x64, I had not a x86 to test).
- Start Task Manager.
- Start the "Reproduce" application.
- When the MDI form has loaded, hit [Return] key (this will fire a MDIChild form).
- Have a look at task Manager, showing how the "Reproduce" app will saturate one of the CPUs of your
  machine and occupy about 650 MB of your RAM.
- After about 45-60 seconds a MDIChild form will appear.
- Close the MDIChild form.
- Hit [Return] again and see the MDIChild appearing almost istantly and Task Manager showing no CPU saturation or RAM increases

As I told, before Win 8 the MDIChild (with binding and SQL acces to various tables) appeared in about 2-3 seconds.

Source files are not so interesting to see: they will just show a MDIparent form calling a MDIChild form, but I have included them in the .ZIP file if you want to do some experiments.

MANY thanks in advance for your time.

Let me know what I can do to solve this problem. Any suggestions is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling the application?   Are you targeting mixed platforms?  Try targeting x86.   I had a similar issue that was resolved by targeting x86 when I compiled, which should work fine on your x64 box unless you have some crazy x64 dependencies in your application.  Note that this will change the clickonce manifest, which is a headache, but I'm curious if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this old issue. Since i had no answer here, i discussed this issue in MSDN forums. Don't ask me how the problem was solved, but you can find the whole story here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/a13be408-1cef-4b39-9f23-7b80779e1fbb
BTW, now it works with compiler set for "any CPU", which is what I want for my application.